WPF: MultiDataTrigger condition - Must have non-null value for 'Binding'
I' ve applied a style to textbox. It'll be shown when the validation has some errors.
Everything work as expected, but know I would like to add a tiny customization:
the style need to be shonw if validation has some errors and a boolean property is set to true. I try to add an tiny example below.
I defined the below  style inside the view
 <UserControl.DataContext>
     <vm:TestValidationViewModel></vm:TestValidationViewModel>
 </UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="errorStylePceInputForm"
           TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdornedElement.ToolTip
                           ,ElementName=errorControl}"
                                   Foreground="Red" />
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                            <Path Fill="#C75C5C"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <EllipseGeometry  Center="32,32"
                                                          RadiusX="32"
                                                          RadiusY="32">
                                        </EllipseGeometry >
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M16.954,48c-4.4,0-6.2-3.118-4-6.928L28,15.012c2.2-3.811,5.8-3.811,8,0l15.046,26.06    c2.2,3.811,0.4,6.928-4,6.928H16.954z">
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M34,32c0,1.105-0.895,2-2,2l0,0c-1.105,0-2-0.895-2-2v-8c0-1.105,0.895-2,2-2l0,0c1.105,0,2,0.895,2,2V32z">
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M34,40c0,1.105-0.895,2-2,2l0,0c-1.105,0-2-0.895-2-2l0,0c0-1.105,0.895-2,2-2l0,0    C33.105,38,34,38.895,34,40L34,40z">
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </Path.Data>
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.3"
                                                        ScaleY="0.3" />
                                        <TranslateTransform X="40"
                                                            Y="0">

                                        </TranslateTransform>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="12"
                                       FontStyle="Italic"
                                       Foreground="Red"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       Background="White"
                                       Text="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Validation.HasError"
                               Value="true"></Condition>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding A,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               Value="True">
                    </Condition>

                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                  
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                            Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}
, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

and I declared the following property inside the viewmodel
private bool _myBoolean;
public bool MyBoolean
{
    get { return _myBoolean; }
    set
    {
        this._myBoolean = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyBoolean));
    }
}

During debugging, the below error message is shown

InvalidOperationException: Must have non-null value for 'Binding'.

There is a way to solve it? I need to define a dependecy property? If yes, i need to define the dependency property in a common place accessible to all.
Thanks for your replies.

P.S.: I would like to apply the style only after clicking on a button,
which will update the value of the property to true.

